# freedesktop.org notifications in java

Tags: java, notifications, dbus

there's a freedesktop.org notification system using DBUS. Looks simple enough, but I just can't figure out how to use it in Java.

Can someone please point to some sample code to display a simple message?

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is some code in the [Java-gnome project](http://java-gnome.sourceforge.net/) that may work for you.  Checkout the [org.gnome.notify](http://java-gnome.sourceforge.net/4.0/doc/api/index.html?overview-summary.html) package.  Java-gnome 4.0.12 included some support for the libnotify-api that may be what you are looking for.

The Java-gnome notifications are on my list to work with but I haven't had a chance to use it yet.

Using [the spec](http://www.galago-project.org/specs/notification/0.9/index.html) and the [examples in dbus-java](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-java/dbus-java/dbus-javase14.html#x41-4400014) it is possible to implement the notifications if the java-gnome library doesn't work for you.

Comment: Java-gnome is exactly what I was looking for.
Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score -1):

How about [documentation](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-java/dbus-java/)? :-)

Comment: I'm reading this one for a few days already. Call me stupid but I still don't get it.

I don't see how to apply this docu http://www.galago-project.org/specs/notification/0.9/x408.html of the notification API to how Java uses DBus.

Comment: http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-java/dbus-java/dbus-javase13.html#x38-4300013.2 shows how to send a message to the bus, which is what you asked, if I understood right. I have no slightest idea of Galago-Project's specs, though.